# Do we need the here's-how-it-works-banner on the help center for experienced users?

Tags: feature-request, help, help-center, help-text, tour

In the new Help Center, we have a banner which is the same as the banner we already had on the homepage for users that weren't logged in. This is the homepage:

[image]

And this is the help center:

[image]

I'm going to find this banner very annoying. I'm experienced enough to know *that*.

**Could the banner in the help center get a minify-button as well?** Something that remembers that he shouldn't show the banner, for always?

Comment: Same suggestion plus some: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217061/can-we-continue-to-show-the-take-a-tour-banner-after-a-user-has-created-an-acc?rq=1

Comment: @JasonC that's related, but not the same.

Comment: Wait. Yeah, just related (barely). Initially I saw *"continue showing this banner until one of the following conditions are met ... The user chooses to hide the banner"* as incidentally covering your issue too. But now I realize that one is only about the main page not the help center too. Whoops.