# The tour is even less prominent than before

Tags: feature-request, new-users, tour

#### What happened

The last time I checked (which was quite some time ago), new users encountered a blurb like this on the front page:

[image: Excerpt of former new-user blurb]

Nowadays, this blurb still exists on individual questions, but the link to the tour is gone:

[image: Current new-user blurb]

On the front page, the blurb is completely missing:

[image: Screenshot of SE when not logged in]

The only way to reach the tour or some information on how the site works is through that small question-mark button on the top bar. If a new user clicks on *Ask Question,* they are not confronted with any hint that something like the tour might exist either.

#### Why this is bad

I know that even when the hints existed, few users took the tour or visited the help centre (which is prominently linked in the tour) before posting.
But now even those who really want to do things right have no realistic chance to inform themselves.
Moreover, if somebody ignored the links in the old days, the potential for being disgruntled was lower since they could not deny that they ignored something.

#### What I wish for

I know, we’ll get the question wizard and other great stuff for new users in 6–8 weeks. But can we please have some hint at the tour back until then?

Comment: *"we’ll get the question wizard and other great stuff for new users in 6–8 weeks"* - 6-8 weeks *on SO* that is anyway.

Comment: But the tour is really bad...it explains so little: [The tour wastes too much time on unspecific stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331956/399694)

Comment: Somewhat related (but rather old) post: [Can we continue to show the "Take a tour" banner after a user has created an account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217061)