# The tour wastes too much time on unspecific stuff

Tags: feature-request, tour

After signing up for a new site, the thing you are most prominently told to do (to get a badge) is read the tour.

[The tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) is...bad.

- The top summary is very generic. Out of the 55 words in Science Fiction's version, only 14 aren't identical on every site.
- Only one of the six sections with the fancy animations is about the site specifically — the one about what is on-topic. The rest are all the exact same (except for having a different exampled post shown).

  - Out of all the things someone should know before posting, **what is on-topic is by far the most important**.
  - What you shouldn't ask (i.e. Primarily Opinion-Based questions, Too Broad questions) is also only mentioned in the one box.

I propose:

- Having the top summary be much more specific. A lot of people are **only going to read the summary** — [Columbia University and the French National Institute found that 59% of the time people share links without clicking on them](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-intersect/wp/2016/06/16/six-in-10-of-you-will-share-this-link-without-reading-it-according-to-a-new-and-depressing-study) — **so it should be as useful as possible.
- Moving the stuff about what's on-topic to the top. It is much more important than the other stuff, especially the thing in front of it; stuff from this section such as "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat" could easily integrate into the on-topic section.

**This page should more prominently explain what is on-topic, because the first badge you are told to get makes you read (or scroll through) it.**

Comment: related: [Usability issues for first-time Stack Exchange users - a micro-study](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279661/165773) and [Ways to give users some specific education about question quality and topicality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277607/165773)

Comment: Site scope in all honours, but at the end of the day a lot of the things *are* the same across all the sites, among them first and foremost the entire Q&A architecture. The tour isn't there to let you know what's on-topic, it's there to let you who has enever ever used an SE site know how such a things even works in the first place. Any user with reasonable SE experience ought to know that he might want to look at the help for determining the actual site scope. Swamping newbies with specific site intricacies instead of what a question and a comment is would actually be "wasting time".

Comment: The [Grand Tour](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLTbIqtg8Gb0pdq7RBIxAdtw7HGb1jimPg).

Answer (score 6):

I think that this is something that you should take up with the moderators of that particular site via writing a Meta Q&A on that site's Meta.

The [Tour of the GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) has been customized much more at its beginning than the site you mention.  Modifications from the original text have been done incrementally over the years using a series of Meta GIS SE Q&As.

Finding what is on-topic already gets linked to near the bottom of every Tour, where there is a **Visit the Help Center** button, but if you want that link or a summary of what's on-topic at the top of your Tour then just ask your community and its moderators to do that.

[image]

Comment: The problem affects the whole network—the tour is inherently badly-designed for telling people how to use specific sites. The template should change, rather than just individual sites fixing their own versions.

Comment: @Stormblessed Yet the only specific thing you listed that affects the whole network is placing the on-topic section one box up. The thing about making the summary more specific is exactly what this answer tells you is already possible and to be done by the specific site moderators. Those are the only two specifc suggestions, the rest stays rather fuzzy other than that it's "bad" for some reason, while staying unclear about what highly relevant site-specific, albeit network-affecting, information you'd want to be captured there in a systemic way that doesn't come down to changing a text.